# IE 8, CSS-repeat-x and relative not working at all

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've got a big issue concerning the background of my header.

I've been tweaking the site for a few hours in IE, since the page is perfect in every other browser, however old they may be. But i'm totally losing my mind on IE 8, since my header-background (a .gif) simply won't repeat itself ONLY horizontally.

As said before, it's great in every other browser, even IE6,7 and 9, but in IE 8 the background just pastes itself over the whole site.

**the css:**

```
header{
position:relative;
height:615px;
background:url(/images/1paage-header-bg.jpg) repeat-x center top;
width:100%;
min-width:950px; }
```

I'd appreciate a little help here...

Comment: Can you provide a link?  Does the `img` repeat both x and y or stretch to fill the whole header or the whole page?

Comment: the site is currently not reachable, only through our enterprise-intranet, it will launch when it's ready.
the img should only repeat x, it's 615px in height and 20px width and should just exactly fill out the header, like in every other browser... i hate IE...

Comment: What happens if you remove `center top` from the rule?

Comment: Nothing at all, in fact, it just changes the layout slightly in other browsers... it's as if "repeat-x" isn't recognized by IE8 and generating errors afterwards in the div

Comment: You state it's a .gif file but your code shows a .jpg file. If it's a .jpg, make sure it's saved as RGB and not CMYK. (But this probably isn't the issue)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, i was already changing and tweaking as i asked my question. No, it's RGB, yes, i tried .jpg as well as .gif, .bmp, .tga, .tif and .png; with no difference. But still thanks for your concern

Answer (score 2):

```
background:none;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='ImagePath',sizingMethod='scale');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

It's working in Internet Explorer 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `background-repeat` to `repeat-x` like this:

```
background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

Comment: That's how my code looked like at first, i personally like to write one line per argument. But since that didn't work, I tried in one line... which also didn't work out.
but thanks

Comment: will try and give u a answer soon

Comment: http://blog.case.edu/jeremy.smith/examples/mockups/ie8-bug.html     look at the sites content using firebug or some other thing......

Comment: Already did, still no use... I just don't understand why only IE8 won't do what EVERY (just tried IE 5 and works like a charm) other browser will happily render... I also just tried a few different formats of imgs (.png, .jpg, .gif, .tga, .tif and even .bmp), with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you've structured your site would definitely help.

But, often what is used for horizontally repeating header background is `body`.

http://jsfiddle.net/KMQJd/

Little clarification: Usually body is used if you are already using some sort of background image in html ( which i kinda asumed here.. ) But if you just have a background color and you want to use repeating image at top you should use `html` - `html { background: #777777 url(image.jpg) repeat-x top left; }`

---

I wonder if its the order of your position as first should come vertical and then horizontal.

`background: url(image.jpg) repeat-x top center;`

Comment: transposing it to the body- or html-tag didn't change anything, and i tried changing the order, but still no difference

Comment: When you put it to the body or html make sure that both of them are full width.. Im thinking with the lack of much information.. Your best bet is to get firebug or another developer tool for a browser and look at the element with that.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this i know. It's out of pure frustration that i tried transposing to another tag. I used the IE8 developer tools, the chrome developer tools as well as firebug. There are no direct differences between the 3, and tweaking the css in the IE8-DevTools is not only a pain in the @$# but also not doing anything.
I wouldn't have turned to StackOverflow if I hadn't invested a few hours of nerves on it.

Comment: When you tried to put it in the `body` or `html` ( im asking about this and asked you to try this Because i dont know your structure and with this its easier for me to tell whats going on ) So, when you tried that did you make sure that the width of `body` and `html` extends to the right side of the browser window? It is very unlikely that it wouldnt do that though..

Comment: Did you try this with different browser window width's by the way?

Comment: both, as well the body as the html tag.
and i specified 100% on both html and body tags, then tried it with 99% and 96%, still no difference.
Well, the site's structure is... confidential, i'm not allowed to show more than a few CSS-parts, so what i can tell about the .html is that most of the site resides in the header (which includes also the content of the page) from the body tag, the rest would be pretty much irrelevant anyway. (html-head/head-body-header-content/content-/header-/body-/html)

Comment: Yes i did resize the window, without any difference.
The ONLY thing that works would be to change the header from relative to absolute, but i'd lose the complete layout for the site, what i'd REALLY want to avoid (since only IE8 is the problem here, and a third CSS just for IE8 would be wasteful)

Comment: My best guess at this point is that there is something in the code that is affecting your background. There would be some work arounds but im not big on fixing things with tircky stuff when the original problem stays..

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, just check the syntax in IE8 every space is important, also check in firebug if the image loads? My bad syntax was:

```
background: #fff url(../img/bg_02.png)repeat-x top center;
```

correct one:

```
background: #fff url(../img/bg_02.png) repeat-x top center;
```

in my case the space was the problem. the top and center parameters are obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat x does not work in IE 8. There no other alternative though

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-repeat